# Why was my answer consider a 'rant' against capitalism?

Tags: discussion

my answer on [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/57738/is-using-a-model-for-a-fashion-brand-haram/58213?noredirect=1#comment95753_58213) question was deleted by the moderating team as they considered it a rant against capitalism.

Why so? There is a strand in Islamic thought that is quite consistent with anti-capitalism. The language that I am using is not particularly 'ranting'; its written in a civil manner.

So why the deletion? And why the accusation that it is a rant?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe "rant" means something different to you, but in my circles it refers to a particular form of discourse where someone will express opinionated views on a controversial subject they consider problematic, often a systematic one that they have no actual control over. It is a form a venting that seeks an audience, but is often inconsiderate of how receptive that audience is or if it even cares about the subject at hand.

That is exactly what I saw here. The question had nothing to do with capitalism, the injustices inherent in the system, or the Islamic perspective on it. There is no indication that the OP took or even cared about the complex view of the economy that your answer required in order to valid. Rather, the fact that OP didn't mention it *at all* strongly suggests that it wasn't a particularly important consideration when they asked the question.

And the fact that your arguments against capitalism are concluded by telling the OP to "go along with the non-haram view" anyway just emphasises the fact that they were irrelevant to the actual answer.

If I felt there was enough meat that removing the irrelevant points would still leave a valid answer, I likely would have done so instead of deleting. However, removing the tangential arguments against capitalism would've left *two lines*, a vague assertion supported by a link to a photoshoot for Vogue magazine, which isn't a particularly credible source of Islamic jurisprudence. I did not consider this enough of an answer to warrant keeping.

Comment: There were two sentences in my answer about capitalism - this is hardly a rant - as far as I understand what a rant is...

Comment: if I had written something like CAPITALISM BAD, CAPITALISM BAD, CAPITALISM BAD, CAPITALISM BAD, CAPITALISM BAD ... - then I think you'd be correct to call that ranting; of course they might be protesting, demonstrating or chanting ...

Comment: When I concluded 'to go along with the non-haram point of view', is because, as I explained earlier, that problem was systemic; and thus, far beyond the efforts of any one individual to be able to effect'; nevertheless, that does not mean that it is wrong to acknowledge it as a problem; removing what I said about the wider economy would leave very little - just the assertion that it is not haram and a link to arabic vogue.

Comment: I'd agree, though that perhaps I should have said more about the morality of fashion itself, per se, from the Islamic pov.